# How to let any user without root change specific network(qdisc) settings?

Tags: linux, networking, script, root

I have made a simple router from a Linux PC, for the purpose of simulating poor network conditions using qdisc (netem and tbf).

Now, I want to allow any user to activate specific presets that I have prepared (normal network, high latency, high packetloss), and have their changes be persistent through a reboot. For myself, for now, I have implemented this with some simple root-requiring scripts.

I have read similar questions, and a common answer was not to look for the solution in scripts and describe my problem instead. I am also somewhat new to Linux btw, I have experience programming C professionally (embedded).

What is the best way to allow any non-root user to easily load specific presets (for qdisc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this might be to allow sudo for the specific commands to these users. You can do this by modifying the sudoers file using visudo, and letting all users in a certain group execute the commands.

```
#Cmnd Alias
Cmnd_Alias QDISK_COMMANDS=<your commands>
<mygroup> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: QDISK_COMMANDS
```

That should allow every user in your group to run with sudo and execute the script as necessary. You can find more sudoers documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).